# How to add vertical grid lines in a grouped boxplot in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I want to create a grouped `boxplot` with vertical grid lines in `seaborn`, i.e., at each tick, there should be a vertical line, just as in a regular scatter plot.

Some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

some_x=[1,2,3,7,9,10,11,12,15,18]
data_for_each_x=[]

for i in range(0, len(some_x)):
    rand_int=rnd.randint(10,30)
    data_for_each_x.append([np.random.randn(rand_int)])

sns.set()
sns.boxplot(data=data_for_each_x, showfliers=False)
plt.show()
```

How it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the vertical white grid lines instead of the horizontal lines which you are getting currently. This is one way to do so:

Create an axis object `ax` and then assign this to the `sns.boxplot`. Then you can choose which grid lines to show by using a boolean argument to `ax.xaxis.grid` and `ax.yaxis.grid`. Since you want the vertical grid lines, turn off the y-grid (`False`) and turn on the x-grid (`True`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # define the axis object here
some_x=[1,2,3,7,9,10,11,12,15,18]
data_for_each_x=[]

for i in range(0, len(some_x)):
    rand_int=rnd.randint(10,30)
    data_for_each_x.append([np.random.randn(rand_int)])

sns.set()
sns.boxplot(data=data_for_each_x, showfliers=False, ax=ax) # pass the ax object here

ax.yaxis.grid(False) # Hide the horizontal gridlines
ax.xaxis.grid(True) # Show the vertical gridlines
```

In case you want to show both x and y grids, use `ax.grid(True)`

[image]

Comment: I don't need to turn the horizontal ones off necessarily (so, I'll leave that `ax.yaxis.grid(False)` out), but yes, that's it! Thank you.